# How best to use scipy.integrate's ODE solvers when state is not naturally stored as a vector?

Tags: scipy, memory-management, data-storage

I have a large system of ODEs.  For various reasons, it is natural to store the values of the dependent variables in a multidimensional array.  For example, these values might represent the solution of a PDE at a point in a 2D or 3D grid, after semi-discretization.

The function `scipy.integrate.odeint` takes a vector (i.e., a one-dimensional array) of initial values, and returns back vectors of the same size. If also requires a right-hand-side function $f$ that takes and returns vectors.  So one must flatten the state vector in order to use `scipy.integrate.odeint`.  Meanwhile, inside $f$ it might be convenient to transform the state back to a multidimensional array, compute the derivative, and flatten the derivative array to a vector.

**Is this flattening(for passing to `f`)->unflattening(for working within `f`)->flattening(for returning something from `f`) cycle the correct way to do things? Is there some other, better way to set things up (that might also happen to be efficient by avoiding the flattening/unflattening cycle?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scipy.integrate.odeint` function does not take a vector as input. It takes a function `f`, an initial state `y0` and a vector of points in time `t` (and possibly a bunch of other optional arguments to control the integration strategy). So you will need to provide it with a function that calculates the right-hand-side of your ODE system, which will boil down to flattening (i.e. looping over all your 'bodies' and building a vector `ft` which is the RHS evaluated at time `t`. There is no way around this.

Comment: `y0` is a vector though -- it's only scalar when you have a single ODE (i.e. not a system of ODEs)?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you are using numpy arrays for your data.  The key is to avoid making a copy when you reshape them.  For that, you want to ensure that you are just generating new "views" of your arrays.  Take a look at [the help page for numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).